# How can hyperlinks be programmatically changed in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with 260 cells that contain different hyperlinks. Is there a way to programmatically change the link instead of editing each link?

The 260 hyperlinks are all unique and need to be changed to other unique values. Each link has had text added to the beginning of each link. The existing link (as example) is `javascript:go("http...")` and I need to remove the `javascript:go("` and `")` from each one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific about what you want to do. Are there many hyperlinks which are all pointing to one or two locations and you want to change them all, or there are like many different ones and you are about to change each one of them to another unique hyperlink. Whatever your problem is, I think this tiny Excel add-on might help you:

[kutools for excel](http://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel.html)

It is made to perform things like your problem.

There is also this forum, which works on Excel problems and you will sure get your problem solved in less than 5 hours:

[Excel Forum](http://www.excelforum.com)

Comment: the 260 hyperlinks are all unique and need to be changed to other unique values. Each link has had text added to the beginning of each link. The existing link (as example) is javascript:go("http.........) and I need to remove the "javascript:go(" from each one

Comment: @GailHoefflin Have you tried just using the normal Find/Replace tool?  It can replace values from within formulas, but I'm not sure if it will do hyperlinks.

Comment: Never mind.  My test didn't work for Find/Replace.

Comment: I tried that also on the Find/Replace

Answer (score 0):

You can fix all the hyperlinks by replacing parts of their address using the following code:

```
Sub ClearHyperlinks()
Dim hl As Hyperlink

For Each hl In Worksheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks
    hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "javascript:go(", "")
    hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, ")", "")
Next hl

End Sub
```

Each `Replace()` statement can be used to remove specific sets of characters.  In this case, the first removes `javascript:go(` and the second removes `)`.  If you need additional characters removed, just incorporate them into the statements or add a new line, following the same pattern.  You may need to do some tricky stuff to remove any quotes, as they are also being used by the code itself.  To remove double quotes, you could change the lines to this:

```
hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "javascript:go(" & Chr(34), "")
hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, Chr(34) & ")", "")
```

`Chr(34)` is the code for the double quote.  However, when I played with this just now, Excel changed my double quotes to `%22` which is the URL-sanitized version of the double quote.  In that case, you would want your code to look like this:

```
hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "javascript:go(%22" , "")
hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "%22)", "")
```

To run this code, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to bring up the VBA window, and paste it in to a new or existing module.  If you're only going to run it once, you can just click anywhere within this code and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it.  If you'll have to run this several times, you may want to assign the macro to a button.

Comment: OK-I have added this code to the .xlsm file. (bear with me as I am just a user-not a coder) I also need to remove the last 2 characters of each hyperlink which are ') in each hyperlink. can this piece of code be updated to include this? Also-how do I execute the code to update the hyperlinks?

Comment: @GailHoefflin See the edits that I just added to my answer.

Comment: thank you-worked great and saved me mass amounts of time